# Silverlight open new tab : close with IE 7-8

Tags: silverlight, tabs

I'm using this code to open a new tab from my Silverlight Application (on click button) :

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("\\SERVER\file.docx"), "_blank");
```

Curiously it is working like a charm on IE 9 and Firefox. But in IE 8 and 7 the tab is opening (for 1 sec) and it close's immediately (PopUp Blocker is disabled). If I make an update to IE 9 the problem is fixed.

I have also tested this code :

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("open", new object[] { "\\SERVER\file.docx", "popup" });
```

But I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with Silverlight, because it's only using the **html bridge**:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645076(v=vs.95).aspx

So the different behavior originates from the javascript differences in the browsers.

The window/tab opening is not reliable, because it depends on the actual browser and the settings of the actual user.

Anyway, you should look for these differences here in SO or Google.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick answer!

I am aware that the behavior in JavaScript depends on the used browsers. In fact, I would like to find a code that is running in all browsers and configurations.

I’ve founded this and it seems to work in IE 7, IE 8 and IE 9 :

```
private const string javascript = @"var popup = window.open('', 'blah') ; 
                                    if(popup.location != 'http://www.bing.com' ){
                                        popup.location = 'http://www.bing.com';
                                    }
                                    popup.focus();";

private void navigationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlPage.Window.Eval(javascript);
}
```

I know, it's not very decent... moreover the tab stay open.